# Amazon Web Service. Which ones to use?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I need help.
I have to write an web application in a month. And I must to use AWS.
But I have never used these services. I don’t have much time, but there are a lot of services.
Also i use Java with Spring Boot.

Application:
Cabinet where user can connect to and control a vacuum cleaner.
The application synchronizes with the vacuum cleaner and can turn on, off, adjust the speed, etc.
Accordingly, there is an authorization page.

Please advise what amazon services I can use in my application.

Comment: You'll have to provide a bit more detail about your current application setup

Comment: You will need to specify much more about what is your exact problem. To encourage people to help you, you need to mention what research and effort have you done so far to achieve your task. Ex: which services have you looked so far? what is the specific part of the project you might be having trouble with? What have you tried doing until now?

Comment: Maybe you could find some documentation or a tutorial about creating an application like the one you need to create in AWS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need a web application to be developed.
I would suggest below architecture.
[image]

All AWS components can be programmatically integrated using AWS SDK and Amplify is a wrapper on top of this.

Develop your UI in any JavaScript framework and host it in AWS S3. Using CloudFront you can cache the UI layer. Put an API gateway layer which will intercept all the traffic from your UI. Using AWS Amplify can very much simplify your UI development with a lot of built-in wrapper components. It comes with CLI which can be used for deployment as well.

Host your Spring Boot+DB Driver (or NodeJS/C#/PHP/Python/etc.) Application with Rest API in AWS Beanstalk. BeanStalk can be configured with Load Balancing, Auto Scaling Group, etc. If AWS Beanstalk seems complicated for you, consider using AWS Lambda (Serverless, microservices) architecture.

AWS DynamoDb can be used as the database. Which is again a highly scalable, very flexible NoSQL in this case.

You can leverage AWS Cognito (https://www.slideshare.net/awsugkochi/acdkochi19-enterprise-grade-security-for-web-and-mobile-applications-on-aws)to store User credentials in groups and add permissions and authenticate/authorise the users.

In API Gateway you can configure AWS Cognito Authoriser and protect the APIs from un-authorised calls.

Some of the auxiliary services can be used to integrate email/SMS etc.
AWS SNS (Pub/Sub) + SQS (Queue) -> If you want to decouple any process, you can use  SNS + SQS. You can send e-mails using AWS SES. AWS Route53 is the DNS and your domain can be hosted here.

If you have to upload any files to cloud and store it for users, leverage AWS S3.

You need to protect internet-facing components like API Gateway and Cloudfront using AWS WAF.

All these systems generate logs and it can be accessed from AWS cloudwatch. Your APIs can be monitored for performance and errors using AWS X-Ray.